# How to resolve "broken cache" when installing shiny-server with gdebi

Tags: software-installation, cache, apt-cache

I am trying to install this shiny-server software (https://posit.co/download/shiny-server/) on Ubuntu 22.04.02.

I receive an installation error and can't see any of the details due to this "broken cache" error.  Perhaps this is an Ubuntu error instead of a software error.

How can I fix the cache?

```
~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.5.20.1002-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Failed to satisfy all dependencies (broken cache)
```